# How to access store getter updated value from main.js file in vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to access updated vuex getter from `main.js` file to check whether user is logged in or not. Based on that i take user to login page. In the main.js file i simply accessing store getter like this.

```
var router = new VueRouter({...})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(store.getters['general/isUserLoggedIn'])
    next()
})
```

*general* is the module name.

but when simply log *`store`* it shows object with updated value. but when logging `store.getters['general/isUserLoggedIn']` it shows initial state value. why it is not providing updated value. Is it right way of doing or any alternative way is there.

More details

in *store.js* file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import general from './modules/general'
import other from './modules/other'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        general,
        other
    },
    plugins: [],
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

checking user logged in or not by calling api status
In *App.vue* file

```
axios.get('/api/profile').then((response) => {
    if (response.data.status === 'success') {
        this.setUserLoggedIn(true)
    }
})
```

*actions.js* in general module

```
setUserLoggedIn ({ commit }, data) {
    commit(types.SET_USER_LOGGED_IN, data)
}
```

*mutations.js* in general module

```
const mutations = {
    [types.SET_USER_LOGGED_IN](state, data) {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = data
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register and import ```store```?

Comment: in main.js importing store like this `import { store } from './store'` @Mr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the initial navigation, the login isn't complete yet in the guard, which is why you don't see the value in the console.  It only appears `true` when logging `store` because it's set shortly after the log, and the console updates itself when you log objects/arrays and then click to view their properties.

One way to fix the race condition is to redirect to the home page when the login is complete:

```js
axios.get('/api/profile').then((response) => {
  if (response.data.status === 'success') {
    this.setUserLoggedIn(true)
    this.$router.push('/');  // Route to home page once login is complete
  }
})
```

And before that, redirect to login if the user is not logged in:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isLoggedIn = store.getters['general/isUserLoggedIn'];
  if(!isLoggedIn) {
    return next('/login');
  }
  next()
})
```

- On the initial load, the user will be redirected to the login page.
- Once the login completes, they will be sent back to the home page.

Comment: and also `next()` comes inside `else` condition right?

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah you could put it in an `else` statement, or it will also work the way I showed it.  If the condition is true, the function calls `next('login')` and exits with `return`, otherwise it makes it to the following line where it calls `next`